# gzip Compress js file in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression

Apologies if its a naive question, but I've been struggling with it for some time. I have a very simple Nodejs application, all it has is a `client.js` file which is pretty large, apart from that there's a `package.json` and a `README.md` I am looking for a way to `gzip` compress this file using some npm package. I've done this in past using Express's `compression` middleware but I dont want to add Express to this application only to be able to use ` of its middleware.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Compress with what? Plain zlib? gzip? xz? Something else?

Comment: Sorry should have added this in the description, am looking for gzip

Comment: Have you seen the built-in [`zlib`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/zlib.html) module? It can do gzip.